# Textbook of p-adic hodge theory

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

It seems that p-adic hodge theory is essential ingredient in arithmetic geometry. I would like to learn p-adic hodge theory, so I have searched for textbooks of p-adic hodge theory, but I wasn't able to find it except for books for specialists who already know a lot about it. I slightly have a background in number theory, abstract algebra and category theory, but no background in differential geometry, hence I would like to read textbooks not required that notion. Does such books exist?

Comment: This question looks a bit off-topic here. Anyway there are many introductory notes on $p$-adic Hodge theory, written by various specialists of the topic, usually available on their websites. These are a good resource. Note however that you probably cannot avoid some sort of notion in differential geometry. E.g. you will have difficulty building intuition about de Rham representations.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll do some more research. By the way, I don't require an intuition. I look for books of p-adic hodge theory where definitions, theorems and proofs are self-contained.

Comment: Have you tried the notes by Brinon and Conrad? I suppose there are references in there too.

Comment: In the book by Gouvéra "p-adic Numbers An Introduction" he writes "p-adic Geometry is a difficult subject, not least because there are many different approaches to the foundations. Perhaps the best place to start is "p-adic Geometry" by Matthew Baker, Brian Conrad, Samit Dasgupta, ... "He gives other references "Bosch, Güntzer Non-Archimedean Analysis", "Berkovich, Spectral Theory and Analytic Geometry over Non-Archimedean fields" "Abbes Éléments de Géometrie Rigide" "Fresnel and van der Put Rigid Analytic Geometry and Its Applications" "Fujiwara, Kato Foundations of Rigid Geometry I"

Comment: @WhatsUp why would it be off-topic here?

Comment: The usual recommendation is the lecture notes by Brinon and Conrad. BUT their approach is somewhat outdated: the modern method is to define everything via the Fargues-Fontaine curve.

Comment: Based on your background, why are you jumping to $p$-adic Hodge theory? For example, do you have a good understanding for the $\ell\ne p$ story? For many applications, it's perfectly fine to keep $p$-adic Hodge theory as a black box.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I think that $p$-adic Hodge theory is not that horrendous (if the OP is interested in), and Bhatt's notes (http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bhattb/teaching/prismatic-columbia/) seem quite accessible to those who know nothing about rigid analytic geometry, Huber spaces, etc., and no strange concepts like classical constructions of Fontaine's period rings are unnaturally introduced. Commutative algebra suffices.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. I will try to read those books.